# How to add dependence between random vectors using a copula?

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, copula

I understand that copulas can be used as a tool to add any conceivable dependence to a pair of random **variables**. However, I would like to add some dependence between two random **vectors**.

Let us suppose that we have random vectors $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $(X_2, Y_2)$. How do we construct their joint CDF, such that they are not independent? Can we use copulae for this purpose?

Let's say $F_1$ is the CDF of $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $F_2$ is the CDF of $(X_2, Y_2)$. Then $$
\Phi_1(x_1, y_1) := F_1(F^{-1}_{X_1}(x_1), F^{-1}_{Y_1}(y_1))
$$ is the copula that captures the relationship between $X_1$ and $Y_1$. Similarly,

$$
\Phi_2(x_2, y_2) := F_2(F^{-1}_{X_2}(x_2), F^{-1}_{Y_2}(y_2))
$$ 
is the copula of $X_2$ and $Y_2$.

In order to add a dependency between $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $(X_2, Y_2)$ we would need a special copula $\Phi(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$, whose marginal distributions with respect to the two pairs of variables are the two partial copulae:
$$
\lim_{x_1 \to \infty \\ y_1 \to \infty} \Phi(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2) = \Phi_2(x_2, x_2) 
$$
and 
$$
\lim_{x_2 \to \infty \\ y_2 \to \infty} \Phi(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2) = \Phi_1(x_1, x_1) 
$$

How can I construct such a copula? Are there some off-the-shelf copulae especially designed for the purpose of modelling inter-vector dependencies?